# Create dummy variables for non excluding categories in R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I want to create a binary representation of categories. I know how to do it for excluding categories (using caret package) but not an straighforward way to do it for non-excluding categories. For instance

`movies <- data.table(movie=c( "batman", "bighero6"), type=list("action",c("action","animation")))
      movie             type
1:   batman           action
2: bighero6 action,animation`

I would like to obtain something like

            `action  animation
batman      1           0
bighero6    1           1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
 dcast(movies[,.(type=unlist(type)) ,movie], movie~type, length)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much